# Why docker image is removed at the end of the tests when using testcontainers?

Tags: testcontainers

I'm using Testcontainers:

```
protected static JdbcDatabaseContainer<?> platformPostgresContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:13")
//      .withReuse(true)
      .withInitScript("create-databases.sql");
```

Why without the `.withReuse(true)` the `postgres:13` image sometimes disappears from Docker at the end of the tests?

Comment: are you using the @Container decorator?

Comment: no, I'm not using the `@Container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design, the lifecycle of containers managed by Testcontainers can be hooked into the test framework, but will ultimately not extend the life of the JVM process (unless the alpha feature `resusable` mode is used).

Comment: what is the recommended way to avoid this if the integrations tests server has no network access (from security reasons) and therefore I cannot afford to automatically delete images?

Comment: The image itself is not removed (Testcontainers will only remove images it builts itself and also this is configurable), only the container. Which CI system are you using? You might have another process that performs this cleanup.

Comment: no, the image is removed, see the source code of Ryuk, also tested locally, after running Ryuk got this log message 'Removed 0 container(s), 0 network(s), 1 volume(s) 15 image(s)' and the postgres:13 image disappeared

Comment: After running Ryuk yourself, or after using it in conjunction with Testcontainers? This is a big difference. Ryuk removes the labeled resources only. `cli.ImagesPrune` is called without `all` flag. Can you share a reproducer example that uses Testcontainers?

Comment: Ryuk is calling the `cli.ImagePrune()` with "dangling=false" as filter, thus try `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http://localhost/v1.41/images/prune --data-urlencode 'filters={"dangling":{"false": true}}'`, this command remove unused images on my computer

Comment: Ryuk adds additional filters to the prune call (see https://github.com/testcontainers/moby-ryuk/blob/master/main.go#L151). It might be the case, that you are running a version of Docker, that did not yet support additional filters.

Comment: Yes, this was the cause, upgraded from Docker 1.13 to 20.10 and the issue is no more present. Thank you. Also checked the doc page for remote API 1.26 (specific for Docker 1.13) and the additional filtering with `label` is not present (i.e. not supported): https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.26/#operation/ImagePrune

Answer (score 3):

The image is deleted by Ryuk, if the environment variable `TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true` is not specified, then Testcontainers will start the [Moby Ryuk](https://hub.docker.com/r/testcontainers/ryuk) container which in turn when will receive `SIGTERM` will remove all containers with label `org.testcontainers=true`, then will remove all images without containers (see the argument of `cli.ImagesPrune` from function `prune` in [moby-ryuk/main.go](https://github.com/testcontainers/moby-ryuk/blob/master/main.go#L194)). Thus, if the only `postgres:13` containers where those created by Testcontainers, then after their remove, the `postgres:13` image will have no associated containers and will be removed too by Ryuk.